# Microsoft Edge spell checker language selection

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, spell-checking, hotmail

How do I select the language for the Microsoft Edge spell checker using www.hotmail.com? It seems to ignore the MS-Office settings. It displays the language in use at the left bottom, however I cannot change it the way MS-Office apps do. I cannot change the Windows10 settings.
It looks like automatic language detection does not work in Edge/Hotmail.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the language or add languages in the Internet Options panel. You can reach this by doing a Windows Search for "Internet Options." Under the General tab and heading "Appearance" find the button "Languages." There you can adjust the language settings.

Note that this requires a restart of the browser, so copy text you have already written into forms to some text file for backup.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unnecessary step of going to Internet Options. Just windows search for Time & Language, thats is configurations Internet Options shortcut opens.